# why sometimes segfault in R when specifying custom linetypes?

Tags: r, graphics

Why do I get R-crashing segfaults when specifying custom linetypes in R?  The four linetypes below are effectively identical, in that they cycle through the same size of dashes and spaces in the same order (they just start at different points in the cycle).

```
plot.new()
abline(0.1,0,lty='28282383') # works
abline(0.2,0,lty='83282823') # works
abline(0.3,0,lty='28238328') # segfault
abline(0.4,0,lty='23832828') # segfault
```

Here is the full error message for the first of the two deadly lines above:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xbf981000, cause 'memory not mapped'
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Segfaults that are reproducible wiuth a current version of R should be sent to the r-devel mailing list.

Comment: They should be tested against R-patched first. Or you'll get Ripleyed.

Comment: confirmed in `R Under development (unstable) (2012-07-27 r60013)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the Cairo graphics device - I get a crash with a default `X11()` graphics device but not with `X11(type="Xlib")` or `pdf()`. RStudio possibly works because it possibly uses its own methods to capture the graphics.

I don't see anything about this in the description of 2.15.1-patched:

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-2.15.1patched.html

so I tried that and have now reported it as a bug:

https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15055

Comment: Bug 15055, Fixed in r-devel r 60791

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me via RStudio on a mac. What OS? What version of R?

```
> plot.new()
> abline(0.1,0,lty='28282383') # works
> abline(0.2,0,lty='83282823') # works
> abline(0.3,0,lty='28238328') # segfault
> abline(0.4,0,lty='23832828') # segfault
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.7.1    stringr_0.6.1 tools_2.15.0
```

[image]

Comment: I can replicate the crash on Ubuntu 64 bit. R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)